# Make sub lists of descending values from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm new to programming. I started doing this question where I have to make sub-lists of descending values from the given list.

```
input_list=[7,1,6, 17, 18, 25, 25, 21, 11, 5 ,3 ,3,26,25]
```

The expected output should be :

```
descend_lists=[[7, 1], [25, 25, 21, 11, 5, 3, 3], [26, 25]]
```

I've no idea where to start from. The idea I have in my mind is I check `ith` and `ith+1` elements together if `ith` element is greater than `ith+1` element then add both elements to `descend_list`. Please help me out.

Comment: What criterion was used to generate `descend_lists`?

Comment: @norok2 `descend_lists` is a list of lists and every list present in `descend_lists` should be sorted in descending order.

Comment: but why not e.g. `[[5, 3], [7, 1], [26, 25], ...]` or any other *"valid"* combination?

Comment: In question it's mentioned the sequence should not be disturbed and minimum number of sublists.

Comment: what does that mean? To sort a sequence you must necessarily modify the order of the element unless it is already sorted. In your very example, the order is modified.

Comment: I mean i saw this question on some site. Given an array. its should be split into sub-lists where each sublist should have its `ith` value greater than `ith+1` elements value

Comment: And split it into minimum number of sublists also

Comment: yes this correct answer but `[[5, 3], [7, 1], [26, 25], ...]` but we get more sublists

Comment: I'm sorry. English is not my primary language. Not able explain to you properly.

Comment: `[[26, 25, 25, 25, 21, 18, 17, 11, 7, 6, 5, 3, 3, 1]]` also sorted, and only one `list`. What is wrong with that "solution"?

Comment: I'll try explain better now . We are given an `input_array=[7,5,4,5,4,3,4,2,1]`. The desired output should be `[[7,5,4],[5,4,3],[4,2,1]].`

Comment: Here see each sublist is in descending order. Now the task is to divide it such that we have minimum number of sublists.

Comment: even `[[7,5],[4],[5,4,3],[4,2],[1]]` is also correct but we have more sublists

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it would be to iterate over the original list considering a temporary list consisting of the current sub-list with descending order and pop it once it stops being in descending order.

```
def sublists(l):
    result = [] # the list of sub-lists
    sublist = [] # temporary sub-list kept in descending order
    for i in range(len(l)):
        sublist.append(l[i]) # add the element
        if(i == len(l) - 1 or l[i] < l[i+1]):
            result.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
    return result
```

In the if statement, what's happening is that you're stopping either when you reach the end of the list (i == len(l) - 1) or when you reach the end of the descending order (l[i] < l[i+1]). Notice, you need to write `i == len(l) - 1 or l[i] < l[i+1]` instead of `l[i] < l[i+1] or i == len(l) - 1` otherwise you'd get an OutOfBounds error (accessing `l[i+1]` is illegal at that point.)

This will preserve all the elements in the list and produce all singletons for sorted lists (with distinct elements) instead of simply throwing them away. This, and the fact that I believe the code is nicer to read for a beginner in this form, is why I add my answer here over the answer of @Ch3steR

Comment: `[[7, 1], [6], [17], [18], [25, 25, 21, 11, 5, 3, 3], [26, 25]]` this is the output im getting for your code. but i dont want [6] , [17] , [18]

Comment: @Jad Issa I threw those elements because OP wanted them to be thrown. Logically they shouldn't be you are right. And your code looks elegant. Deserves upvote.

Comment: Great! Then this offers a slightly different solution; I hope this helps for reference purposes!